# regex substitution

Tags: regex, perl

I'm in the process of trying to learn more about regular expressions and I've been wondering about the following:

How to insert a space after a dot character, but only when the dot character is not surrounded by numbers, e.g. it needs to match . but not 22.22!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a nice case of **[zero-width assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**:

```
$subject =~ 
    s/(?<=\.         # after a dot,
        (?!          # but not matching
          (?<=\d\.)  # digit followed by dot before, AND
          (?=\d)     # digit afterward
        )
      )/ /x
    g;
```

I think that you will find the comments self explanatory! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
echo "22.22"|perl -pe 's{(\D)\.(\D)}{$1. $2}'
22.22
echo "2x.x2"|perl -pe 's{(\D)\.(\D)}{$1. $2}'
2x. x2
```